# Minimizing SecureRandom performance problems in multithreaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, encryption, thread-local

(This is with Java 8 and Tomcat 8 on SLES, FWIW.)

How worried do I need to be about performance problems with `SecureRandom` (specifically the `SHA1PRNG` algorithm of the `SUN` provider) *after* the initial seeding when I am using a single `SecureRandom` instance in multiple threads? `SecureRandom` is thread-safe so that implies some level of potential contention?

I don't see anything in Java 8 Javadocs that discusses this for `SecureRandom` though I see that the Javadocs for `Random` do specifically warn about contention and performance degradation when using a single `Random` instance across threads.

We are considering using a single `SecureRandom` instance because from what we see it is way too expensive to get a new `SecureRandom` instance within our `encrypt()` method (which uses `SecureRandom` for IV generation) because of the seeding overhead kills you if you use a new `SecureRandom` very few times before you are done with it.

We are alternatively considering having a static `ThreadLocal<SecureRandom>` member of the class containing the `encrypt()` method so that a single `SecureRandom` is used per thread.  We would intentionally **not** call `ThreadLocal.remove()` because if we went this route we would actually like the instance to "live" in the tomcat threads as long as possible (to minimize the number of times new `SecureRandom` instances are created).

From reading here about `ThreadLocal` memory leaks I have some concerns about that approach.  However, we literally **never** redeploy the webapp.  It is used in an embedded system and when the webapp is upgraded (which is part of an overall system upgrade and only happens a few times a year) Tomcat is completely shut down, the new war file dropped down, and Tomcat restarted.  That would seem to be to make the webapp-related `ThreadLocal` leaks moot.

So, is there any good data out there on how "contentious" `SecureRandom` is, and is there consensus on how to most properly use `SecureRandom` in a heavily-multithreaded environment?

Comment: Are you sure the seeding overhead kills you? I would expect it to be quite fast in Linux environments where /dev/urandom is used for seeding. Also, how big is a typical message that you are encrypting in your encrypt method? It may be that there is not much contention for a single SecureRandom instance after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `SecureRandom`, it uses a `synchronized` method, so any discussion out there about `synchronized` in a heavily-multithreaded environment would be applicable.

Given this note (as you mentioned) in the `Random` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), I'd say that your plan to use `ThreadLocal<SecureRandom>` is appropriate:

> Instances of `java.util.Random` are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same `java.util.Random` instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using `ThreadLocalRandom` in multithreaded designs.

As you concluded yourself, you won't have memory leak issues with your implementation. This is especially true because the objects stored in the `ThreadLocal` are from the system ClassLoader, not your webapp's ClassLoader.